# Can I add validation to Excel's ShowDataForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited a workbook from someone who is long gone. They put a button on the dashboard that activates the following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheet5.ShowDataForm
End Sub
```

It brings up a form with all the elements/columns on that sheet, with all the buttons need to put in more data. I like the simplicity, but is there any way I can add in validation? Things like:

- In the 7 fields it collects, 5 are required.
- In the first field, I want to make sure a number is entered and that number isn't on the list already.

I can code these, I just don't seem to have an entry point into the *DataForm*.

Thanks!
Chuck

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013. I am on the Sheet's code page, bring up `Worksheet_SelectionChanged()`, but I don't have ShowDataForm on the drop-down.

Comment: The only choices on the left drop down are `(General)` and `Worksheet`.

Comment: No luck with the Ctrl-F, either.

Comment: `ShowDataForm` is a method of the worksheet. If you type it in and follow to its definition, you end up in the Worksheet class.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it's infinite simplicity implies zero flexibility. Those two should be inversely proportional, eh?

Comment: Ya.. noticed it right now... need to do some tests... may take while... but as it looks right now, your request is not possible by the buildin feature... I will still give it a shot ;)

Answer (score 0):

While that won't be the answer you like to hear, but according to [THIS](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19238-ShowDataForm-and-data-validation), your request can't be done in a simple way. So either create your own userform  or dive extremely deep in the win api.   Sorry :(